# TWEEPY STREAM: my timeline tweets

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I need to catch the tweets I recieve in my timeline from the people I follow.

The code I have is:

```
*import sys  
import tweepy 
from tweepy import Stream 
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

CONSUMER_KEY = 'fgdg'  
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'fdgdfgdf' 
ACCESS_KEY = 'fgdfgd'  
ACCESS_SECRET = 'dfgdfgdfg' 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)  
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)  
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener()) 
twitterStream.filter(track=["order"])*
```

But this give me the PUBLIC STREAM. I only want MY TIMELINE STREAM

Comment: `twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener()) ` i get error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_data.py", line 32, in <module>
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of the `track` method of the `Stream` object, you can use the `userstream` method of the `Stream` object. This returns only the data that appears on a user's personal timeline. To further limit the tweets returned, you might want to pass `_with='user'` to `userstream`. This limits the returned events to events only concerning the authenticated user, not their followings.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
twitterStream.userstream(encoding='utf8')
```

instead of

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["order"])*
```